# Can't access dynamic html using html-webpack-plugin with express server

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Recently, I want to use html-webpack-plugin in my project, but face a problem. 
Here is part of my server.js and webpack.dev.config.js

server.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
{
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const config = require('./webpack.development.config');
    const compiler = webpack(config);

    app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler,
    {
        noInfo: true,
        publicPath: '/'
    }));

    app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
}

    app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/asset','index.html'));
    });
```

webpack.dev.js

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './public/enter.html',
        filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new PreloadWebpackPlugin()
]
```

I can access this directly like http://localhost:3000.
It's supposed to be accessed by any path e.g.http://localhost:3000/counter, but get

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   '/Users/paulhuang/Documents/workspace/react-redux-template/public/asset/index.html'

I use npm run build to create a harddisk index.html, and solved the problem.

Any other better idea? Thanks!

Comment: `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/asset','index.html'));` The problem is here, when using webpack-dev-server you don't have a "on disk" html file, so it wont work... I'll post an answer later on this

Comment: @MatheusSilva thank you:)